# Postgres make_date handle exception

Tags: postgresql

So I'm storing the user's birthday and month. I'm sending them birthday deals and these deals expire each at a different interval, that is "number of days after their birthday".

I have constructed the formula successfully (below is a chunk of it) but am left with this problem:

`('2015-10-10'::date >= make_date(2015, users.birth_month, users.birth_day)` ...

If the user was born on Feb 29, `make_date` would raise an exception for invalid years ( `ERROR:  date field value out of range: 2015-02-29` )

How can I gracefully handle this? (I have other ways of handling this but they require me to give special treatment for leap years)

Comment: Do you think this would affect efficiency at all? (versus my solution below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have added a special case for when the birthday is 02-29. This would solve my problem but I would totally love to hear other suggestions.

```
('2015-10-10'::date >= 
   case when users.birth_month = 2 and users.birth_day = 29 make_date(2015,2, 28)
        else make_date(2015, users.birth_month, users.birth_day)
   end
)
```

The user in this case would lose a day (I can make them win a day by doing march 1st) but you get the point =)

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using  combination of `make_date` and `interval` PostgreSQL fucntions (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html for more info).

The trick is to ensure the date from `make_date` is always valid.  This can be easily achieved by using the 1st day of the month and then use `interval` (minus 1 day) to increment the desired number of days (while avoiding `ERROR:  date field value out of range` errors).

This is exemplified by creating a little table `users`: -

```
create table users ( 
  id serial primary key,
  birth_day integer,
  birth_month integer
);
```

... and populating it with some data ...

```
insert into users (birth_day, birth_month) values
                  (1,         2),
                  (28,        2),
                  (29,        2),
                  (30,        2),
                  (31,        2);
```

If the year is `2015` you can run the following query: -

```
select birth_day,
       birth_month,
       make_date(2015, birth_month, 1) + (birth_day  - 1) as birthday
  from users;

╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ birth_day ║ birth_month ║   birthday   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║         1 ║           2 ║ "2015-02-01" ║
║        28 ║           2 ║ "2015-02-28" ║
║        29 ║           2 ║ "2015-03-01" ║    <---- wrapped to march 1st
║        30 ║           2 ║ "2015-03-02" ║
║        31 ║           2 ║ "2015-03-03" ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

However, if the year is `2016` (leap year) then it's: -

```
select birth_day,
       birth_month,
       make_date(2016, birth_month, 1) + (birth_day  - 1) as birthday
  from users;

╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ birth_day ║ birth_month ║   birthday   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║         1 ║           2 ║ "2016-02-01" ║
║        28 ║           2 ║ "2016-02-28" ║
║        29 ║           2 ║ "2016-02-29" ║
║        30 ║           2 ║ "2016-03-01" ║    <---- wrapped to march 1st
║        31 ║           2 ║ "2016-03-02" ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

> Thanks `a_horse_with_no_name` for pointing out that you don't need to use `interval` if it's days - simple addition is all you need i.e. `+ ((birth_day  - 1) || ' days')::interval` can be simplified to `+ (birth_day  - 1)`